# aapt dump badging error while trying to publish an Android apk on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I am getting this problem when publishing android apk file on Google Play.

[image: error in uploading apk file in google play]

This is my AndroidManifast.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="xx.com"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/main_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
     >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
        />

    <activity
        android:name="xx.com.MainActivity"
        android:label="@style/AppTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity> 
    <activity
        android:name="xx.com.Images"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity> 
    <activity
        android:name="xx.com.Awards"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>   
     <activity
        android:name="xx.com.Magazine"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>    
      <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

</application>
```

I tried many stackoverflow.com examples but failed. Apk is working fine in device and emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be your problem

```
<activity
    android:name="amithanda.com.MainActivity"
    android:label="@style/AppTheme" >
```

label should be a String value.

```
  android:label="@string/app_name"
```

FYI : [Developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) gives you an idea

```
android:label="string resource"
```

Comment: I will check and tell you..Thanks.